# Tracking Textbox Entries with Google Analytics

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-analytics, sitecore

I am trying to capture in google analytics the data that is entered into a textbox. The code that I have so far is below, I am trying to capture the data by Javascript, but I can't seem to get it to work. The CMS Platform I am using is sitecore.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SalesRepSearch.ascx.cs"     Inherits="USEndoscopy.Website.layouts.USEndoscopy.Sublayouts.SalesRepSearch" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="USEndoscopy.Library.Search" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var textbox = document.getElementById('txtZipCode'),
    submitButton = document.getElementById('btnSalesRepSearch');

submitButton.onClick = function () {
    _trackEvent('data-store', textbox.name, textbox.value, 0);
    // 'data-store' can be replaced with whatever category of data you want, for sortability's sake
    // the 0 can be replaced with any other numerical data you want - but it must be numerical
}
</script>
<p></p>
<p>
    <asp:Panel DefaultButton="btnSalesRepSearch" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtZipCode" runat="server" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSalesRepSearch" runat="server" CssClass="buttonregular" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSalesRepSearch_Click" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqTxtZipCode" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ZipCode" ControlToValidate="txtZipCode" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid US Zip code" CssClass="error"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regExTxtZipCode" runat="server"     ValidationExpression="^\d    {5}(-\d{4})?$" ValidationGroup="ZipCode" ControlToValidate="txtZipCode" Display="Dynamic"     ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid US Zip code" CssClass="error"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    </asp:Panel>
</p>

<p>
    <asp:Repeater ID="salesRepContainer" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# ((SalesRep)Container.DataItem).RepName %><br />
            <%# ((SalesRep)Container.DataItem).Phone %><br />
            <a href="mailto:<%# ((SalesRep)Container.DataItem).Email %>"><%# ((SalesRep)    Container.DataItem).Email %></a><br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</p>
<p>
    <sc:Text Field="InternationalMessage" runat="server" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the source code of the rendered HTML? Has the ASP.Net WebControl ID's ended up as something completely different due being nested in the panel?

Maybe you should add a CSS class to these and use [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName)

If you are using jQuery then you could use the [attributeEndsWith](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector

```
$('input[id$="txtZipCode"]');
$('input[id$="btnSalesRepSearch"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `ASP.NET` has changed the `ID` value of your textboxes at the time of rendering them.

If your running .net V4 or greater then add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to your textbox and 
button. This tells .net to not change the ID of your control.

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtZipCode" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSalesRepSearch" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="buttonregular" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSalesRepSearch_Click" />
```

If your running less than .net 4 change your Javascript to: (.ClientID gets the ID that .net gave the control when it rendered it)

```
    var textbox = document.getElementById('<%= txtZipCode.ClientID %>'),
    submitButton = document.getElementById('<%= btnSalesRepSearch.ClientID %>');
```

**UPDATE**

You might be having an issue where your javascript function is trying to assign a `click` function to your button *before* your button is actually available on the DOM.

So try the following:

Javascript function

```
function btnSearchClick(){
     var textbox = document.getElementById('txtZipCode');


     // Change your google code to this:

     _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', textbox.name, textbox.value,  0]);

     return true;
 }
```

And on your button add the property

```
 onClientClick="return btnSearchClick()"
```

Comment: Hi There,I went ahead and tried this adding the client mode to static, with the same javascript that I had before and I am still getting no return in google analytics.

Comment: When looking at this using Firebug in Javascript, I am getting an error stating that SubmitButton is null

Comment: Ok. I played around with this, but now I am getting the error:[10:10:53.583] ReferenceError: _trackEvent is not defined I am using the old style tracking way.

Comment: updated my update. added a return to the call and a return true in the function. This will tell the button to perform its normal postback once the JS function has completed

Comment: Ok. Still getting the error :ReferenceError: _trackEvent is not defined

Comment: Check your google code. put it at the bottom, just before the closing `</body>` tag - your error is saying _trackEvent isn't there.