# Javascript using Google Analytics returning Null Value, data not being captured

Tags: c#, google-analytics, sitecore

I am trying to capture google analytics data for a textbox where a user is typing in a zip code and then clicking the button to search a database. The application is written in C# and here is the code for the button piece:

```
<p></p>
<p>
    <asp:Panel DefaultButton="btnSalesRepSearch" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtZipCode" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSalesRepSearch" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="buttonregular" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSalesRepSearch_Click" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqTxtZipCode" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ZipCode" ControlToValidate="txtZipCode" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid US Zip code" CssClass="error"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regExTxtZipCode" runat="server" ValidationExpression="^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$" ValidationGroup="ZipCode" ControlToValidate="txtZipCode" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid US Zip code" CssClass="error"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
     </asp:Panel>
</p>
```

I am trying to use Javascript to trigger a google analytics event that captures the data from the textbox, the problem is on Page Load I get an error saying that the submit button is Null and nothing will get captured into Google Analytics. Here is the Javascript that I am using below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var textbox = document.getElementById('txtZipCode'),
    submitButton = document.getElementById('btnSalesRepSearch');

    submitButton.onclick = function (txtZipCode) {
        _trackEvent('data-store', textbox.name, textbox.value, 0);
        // 'data-store' can be replaced with whatever category of data you want, for sortability's sake
        // the 0 can be replaced with any other numerical data you want - but it must be numerical
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ASP server side ids like txtZipCode are not the same as the id that is generated on the client side. Do a view source of your html and you can verify that the ids are different. Then change your document.getElementById selectors accordingly.

Comment: The ClientIDMode="Static" takes care of that. I can view the source and the ID's are the same. It is something with the javascript

Comment: Ah.. missed that..Another issue might be that your script executes before the document is loaded on to the browser. You can possibly move the code to a onload function handler.

Comment: @vpd05141989 - why have you created 2 questions that are the same thing? Just complicating your issue :) I've put a solution to your JS issue on my answer over here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808591/tracking-textbox-entries-with-google-analytics/13809089#comment19020327_13809089